# Hover and footer won't cover the whole object

Tags: html, css

I have two questions, so I'm just going to ask them in one post. My hover won't cover the whole object. As you can see here: http://st358373.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/epw/index.php < the white part doesn't cover the whole film poster. I don't know how to fix that. Maybe it's an easy solution, but I can't seem to find it.

Secondly, my footer isn't 100% width. I also don't know how to fix that. I hope you guys can help me with it.

```
<center><table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5"><tbody align="center">

<div><tr><td><div style="width: 200px; height:296px; margin-top: 50px">
<div class="image-hover">
    <img src="images/thor.jpg" width="200px" height="296px"/>
   <span class="desc"><div class="filmtitle">Thor: Ragnarök</div>
       <div style="font-size:8px; text-transform:uppercase; color:#000;">
<div class="black"><div class="filmdiscription"><b>SUMMARY: </b> Thor is imprisoned on the other side of the universe without his mighty hammer and finds himself in a race against time to get back to Asgard to stop Ragnarok, the destruction of his homeworld and the end of Asgardian civilization, at the hands of an all-powerful new threat, the ruthless Hela. But first he must survive a deadly gladiatorial contest that pits him against his former ally and fellow Avenger the Incredible Hulk!<br><br>
<b>Genre: </b><br><br><center> <!--Genre ophalen uit de Database-->
    </span>
</div></div>
</div></div></td>
```

CSS:

```
#title {
 background-color: black;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 9px;
    height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    line-height: 55px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 1019px;
    margin-top: 20px;
   }

.container div {
    display: none;
}

.container:hover div {
    display: block;
}

.filmtitle {
height: 20px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 3px;
background-color: #000;
color:#fff;
font-size: 7px;
line-height: 20px;
font-family: raleway;
}

.filmdiscription {
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 8px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 120%;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: justify;
padding: 15px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
vertical-align: middle;
}

.black {
height: 240px;
background-color: #000000;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-bottom: 9px;
padding-top: 19px;
}


.image-hover>span {
    width:180px;
    height:276px;
    display: block;
margin-top: -296px; background-color: white;  padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -moz-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -o-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    opacity: 0;
}
.image-hover:hover>span {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Footer:

```
<footer>
    <div class="footertekst">© 2017 Nienke. Rechten voorbehouden.</div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.footertekst {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin-top: 50px;

}


footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#619b28+0,427768+100 */
    background: #619b28; /* Old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#619b28', endColorstr='#427768',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Comment: From the code you have shared, it does not appear to show the first problem when run here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEOM0BKS0XWX

The same is true for the footer problem.

Comment: That's so weird...

Comment: I've answered below the fixes.

Also consider changing the cursor when the user hovers over an image: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: That's great idea. I'm going to look into that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem, make the following changes to the CSS:

```
.image-hover>span {
    width: 180px;
    height: 274px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -299px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 9px 10px 13px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -moz-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -o-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

For the second problem, it is actually caused by your navbar. Add the last two lines:

```
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#619b28+0,427768+100 */
    background: #619b28; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%); /* FF3.6-15             */
     /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
     /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#619b28', endColorstr='#427768',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Here is your whole css file with changes made:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#619b28+0,427768+100 */
    background: #619b28; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#619b28', endColorstr='#427768',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

ul.topnav li {display: inline-block;
}


ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}


ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #000000;}


ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

body{
color:#666666;
background-color:white;
background-position:top left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
font-family:arial;
font-size:11px;
line-height: 130%;
text-align:justify;
}

a:link, a:active, a:visited{
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
color:#000;
text-decoration: none;
}


#title {
 background-color: black;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 9px;
    height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    line-height: 55px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 1019px;
    margin-top: 20px;
   }

.container div {
    display: none;
}

.container:hover div {
    display: block;
}

.filmtitle {
height: 20px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 3px;
background-color: #000;
color:#fff;
font-size: 7px;
line-height: 20px;
font-family: raleway;
}

.filmdiscription {
font-family: calibri;
font-size: 8px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
line-height: 120%;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: justify;
padding: 15px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
vertical-align: middle;
}

.black {
height: 240px;
background-color: #000000;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-bottom: 9px;
padding-top: 19px;
}


.image-hover>span {
    width: 180px;
    height: 274px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -299px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 9px 10px 13px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -moz-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    -o-transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    transition: .4s ease-in-out opacity;
    opacity: 0;
}
.image-hover:hover>span {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

h1
{
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #274E89;
}

.contacttext {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #1F1D1D;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

/* Centres the page (this could be container)*/
.body {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:576px;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #999;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}


/* Labels are titles for the text fields. You can use a placeholder instead if you like*/
label 
{
    display:block;
    margin-top:20px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
}

/* Centres the form within the page */
form 
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:459px;
}

/* Styles the text boxes */
input, textarea, file {
    width:439px;
    height:27px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:0.9em;
    color:#3a3a3a;
}

    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        border:1px solid #97d6eb;
    }

/* Styles the text area boxes (message field) */    
textarea 
{
    height:213px;
    background-color: #efefef;
}


/* Styles the submit button */
#submit {
    /* background:url(images/submit.png); */
    width:127px;
    height:48px;
    text-align: center;
    /* text-indent:-9999px; */
    border:none;
    margin-top:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* Styles the submit hover */   
#submit:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #216182;
    opacity:0.9;
}

/* Styles the cancel button*/   
#cancel {
    /* background:url(images/cancel.png); */
    width:127px;
    height:28px;
    text-align: center;
    /* text-indent:-9999px; */
    border:none;
    margin-top:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* Styles the cancel hover */
#cancel:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity:0.9;
}

.footertekst {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin-top: 50px;

}

p.contacttext {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#main {
width:960px;
margin:50px auto;
font-family:raleway;
text-align: center;
}
span {
color:red
}
h2 {
background-color: white;
text-align:center;
border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
margin:-10px -40px;
padding:15px
}
hr {
border:0;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
margin:10px -40px;
margin-bottom:30px
}
#login {
width:600px;
display: inline-block;
border-radius:10px;
font-family:raleway;
border:2px solid #ccc;
padding:10px 40px 25px;
margin-top:70px;
}
input[type=text],input[type=password] {
width:100%;
padding:10px;
margin-top:8px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
padding-left:5px;
font-size:16px;
font-family:raleway
}
input[type=submit] {
width:103.5%;
background-color: #2F8059;
color:#fff;
border:2px solid #2F8059;
padding:10px;
font-size:20px;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius:5px;
margin-bottom:15px;
height: 50px;   

}

 input{
   text-align:center; 
}
label { 
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: .85em;
}

#con {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.links {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

a {
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#619b28+0,427768+100 */
    background: #619b28; /* Old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#619b28', endColorstr='#427768',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Comment: Can't believe it was a small change. Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: These things are very easy to spot using the developer tools. Hit F12 in your browser and you can hover over elements to see what's going on. Then you can change the css live and see results instantly.

Comment: Seriously? I didn't know that. I keep learning things here on Stackoverflow. :)